# Get the position of an image using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to get the position of an image using Jquery.
The only problem is that it only gives me the position where
the image where when the document loaded.

```
$(".frog").click(function(){
    alert($(".frog").position().left);  
});
```

How do I get the position of the image after it been moved?

/Johannes

Comment: How about use $(".frog").offset()?

Comment: Thank, offset made it work:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.position` gives the position relative to the parent
`.offset` gives the position relative to the document