# Responsive web development, scaling overlapping images whilst keeping clickable image in exact location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have been asked to prepare just a single HTML page that has five clickable points. 
The idea behind the clickable points is just to have a pop up that explains some information.

I am able to scale the 100% width / 100% height of my background image (canvas) and it works fine on various devices, but I have images that sit on top of my canvas, and as I scale it down, the canvas scales down ok, but my clickable image does not stay in its exact location. It remains relatively close to its original location, but I need it to stay in its exact location, and also to the scale that the page is being viewed at.

I would really appreciate any help / examples please.

Thanks for any help provided.

Also, please see my link to the page (university):

[HS Web Link](http://www.bbk.ac.uk/~dmcken03/HS2/index.html)

Comment: As per responsive design principles don't use anything absolute but use relative. So instead of using "X px" to define position of an element you can try "X %" or use bootstrap span class to divide the area relatively.

Comment: Thanks! Will amend CSS accordingly. Bootstrap span class? I agree with using % and px. I have been trying lots of things but not doing well. Do you have an example at all please?
Thanks for response.

Comment: Your clickable image is positioned using a percentage of the screen width. As the screen size changes it's position will change too. If you want it fixed, use an absolute position in `px` or other unit.

Comment: <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span3"> this designates a part of 25% to that div. i.e. 3/12. you can go upto span12 i.e. 100% of total area.

Comment: If the percentages do not work (which they should) you might try slicing the image into pieces at the necessary points and moving the clickables to the corner of the proper image corner via javascript as needed.

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonkey. Will try this and let you know how I go.
Thanks for all comments everyone. Very VERY helpful! =]

Comment: Thanks @pathfinder - Do you know of any examples I could look at all? Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @PrimalScientist I'm not entirely sure I see what you're getting at or how CodeMonkey's comments relate to it. Either something is fixed, or it isn't. In reality, if you're scaling to screen size, then things won't move, although their exact positioning may change if the size changes. Relative positioning should be fine, but your question seems to be asking for something else.

Comment: @MikeW - Hey Mike, the only thing I was pointing out was that your comment was, or seemed opposite to that of CodeMonkeys comment above. However, I should have actually tried what you stated in your comment before I actually commented on that particular comment, so, please accept my apologies. I will amend my comment accordingly.
The problem that I have is that as the screen scales down, my 'clickable' image does not. I am looking for a way for my clickable image to remain relative to the screen size it is being viewed at - and also remain in its exact intended location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432500/get-the-position-of-an-image-using-jquery and http://api.jquery.com/offset/ and http://api.jquery.com/position/ - these will show you position of top left corner in relation to document and parent. If your image was precisely cut into pieces with top left corners on the spot you need, no matter the screen size you could gather the coordinates needed to move your "clickables" in place.

Comment: @pathfinder Thanks for this. Really handy!! :)
I will use it. What did you mean with regards to 'slicing the image' exactly? Thanks all by the way. Really helpful.

Comment: literaly cutting it into pieces and putting the pieces together so you would have the background pieced together.

Comment: You can also use a single image and slice it on the canvas. here are the docs on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images